# Will SimpleConsumer is depreciated in coming Kafka Versions ? Will it be good to use high level consumer for manual offset control?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am unable to find SimpleConsumer Support in latest version of kafka 0.10 and 0.11. Is it good to use high level consumer for below use case:

Use case: I want to manually control offsets for each topic and saving in external source.

The problem with High level consumer is for above use case is: 
When I do poll,

1)I am able to get messages, but I don't have control over how many messages to read.

2)I am unable to decide when to stop polling i.e what should be my definition of batch size.

Answer (score 0):

The [KafkaConsumer](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) class has setting `max.poll.records` that specifies what is the maximum number of records could be fetched - by default, there is no limit. `KafkaConsumer` also allows you to control offsets manually, and store them where you want.  The "Kafka: The Definitive Guide" book (freely available from confluent's site) has quite big section about these topics.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the Offset manually by setting **"enable.auto.commit", "false"**, offsets will only be committed when the application explicitly chooses to do so.

**consumer.commitSync();**

API will commit the latest offset returned by poll() and return once the offset is committed, throwing an exception if the commit fails for some reason.

If you wish to have even finer control over which messages have been committed by specifying an offset explicitly.

```
public void commitSync(java.util.Map<TopicPartition,OffsetAndMetadata> offsets)
```

Commit the specified offsets for the specified list of topics and partitions.

This is a synchronous commit and will block until either the commit succeeds or an unrecoverable error is encountered (in which case it is thrown to the caller).

**max.poll.records** => controls the maximum number of records that a single call to poll()